# Jstl: get variable from custom tag

Tags: java, jstl

```
// Template
<%@ tag description="master" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ attribute name="js" fragment="true" %>
<!doctype html>
<c:set var="myVar" value="1" />
<html>
<head>
    <jsp:invoke fragment="js" />
</head>
<body>
</html>

// Page
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>   
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %> 
<t:master>
    <jsp:attribute name="js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/administration/customers.js"></script>
    </jsp:attribute>
</t:master>
```

Is it possible to get acces   to `myVar` from the page? Thank you

Solution 1:
I can declare the variable with `scope="request"`, so I can access to it via `${requestScope.test}`. But is it good way?

Comment: Have you tried `${myVar}`?

Comment: Yes, the page scope doesn't work in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: declare the variable with scope="request" and it will be accessable via ${requestScope.test}.